# Spring xml configuration - list with java.awt.Color values

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I'm trying to inject a list of `Color` from `java.awt.Color` into my bean. In my XML I have:

```
<bean id="twoPlayers" class="basic.TwoPlayer">
            <property name="Colors">
                <list value-type="java.awt.Color">
                    <value>BLUE</value>
                    <value>GREEN</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

The thing is it sees `BLUE` and `GREEN` as `String` so when I run the app I get an error saying type mismatch, can't cast String to Color. But I pointed out the type, so what's the problem? How to do this correctly?

The class:

```
public class TwoPlayer {

  public Color[] Colors;

  public void setColors(Color[] colors) {
    Colors = colors;
  }
  ...
}
```

I know I have ar array here, not a list but I've read it's not a problem for Spring.

Comment: try this new one man.

Comment: please add class file too where u are expecting spring to inject these properties into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by Vinayak Mittal answer (sorry, I can't upvote your answer, I don't have enough reputation), I decided to go with something like this:

```
<bean id="blue" class="java.awt.Color">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="int"><value>0</value></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1" type="int"><value>6</value></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="2" type="int"><value>234</value></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="green" class="java.awt.Color">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="int"><value>29</value></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1" type="int"><value>172</value></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="2" type="int"><value>32</value></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

<bean id="twoPlayers" class="basic.TwoPlayer">
    <property name="Colors">
        <list value-type="java.awt.Color">
            <ref bean="blue"/>
            <ref bean="green"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It's not exactly what I wanted because I have to define the colors myself but it is good enough solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try out this:

```
<bean id="blue" class="java.awt.Color.BLUE" />

<bean id="green" class="java.awt.Color.GREEN" />


<bean id="twoPlayers" class="basic.TwoPlayer">
    <property name="Colors">
        <list value-type="java.awt.Color">
            <ref bean="blue"/>
            <ref bean="green"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And let me know in the comment section if it is helpful or not.

Comment: Still the same error... `Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.awt.Color]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color.BLUE`

Comment: try this one @Nerwena

Comment: Now `Cannot find class [java.awt.Color.BLUE] for bean with name 'blue' defined in class path resource [spring-configuration.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.awt.Color.BLUE`. I have no idea what's wrong, I mean it should't be so hard to do it.

Comment: just try using this @Nerwena **<bean id="blue" class="Color.BLUE" />**

Comment: So Intellij tells me it cannot resolve class or package`Color.BLUE`. Do I need to add something to my xml configuration?

Comment: @Nerwena u have try like this                                                                                                        
                <list value-type="java.awt.Color">
                    <value>Color.BLUE</value>
                    <value>Color.GREEN</value>
                </list>

Comment: Now I get the error from the first comment. I'm really close to dropping the idea of using Spring to do this ;)